# Why can i access the value of b even though it is set to private in the subclass?

Tags: java

```
public class A {

protected int b = 16;

}


public class B extends A{

    private int b=20;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(b.b);
    }

}
```

The output is 20. How can b which refers to an object of type B should not be able to access the private member correct ?

Comment: This is a great example of why one should access members with getters (and setters).

Comment: @Paranaix How so? Getters and setters do not prevent this, quite the contrary.

Comment: Conceptually an attribute called "b" should not be declared twice in the same class hierarchy. It is the same thing that if you declare an attribute called "name" in a class called Entity and in a Entity's subclass called Person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the value of b in class B. B can access its own private members.

Answer (score 2):

`static` methods in a class can access all `private` members of the containing class.

Since your `main` is part of class `B` it can see all of the members.

Answer (score 1):

You can still access it directly from inside the `B` class even if it is `private`. Since the `main` method is located there, the private variable can be accessed.

The variable `b` from the `A` class is hidden by the variable `b` in the `B` class, and can not be reached unless you declare it like this:

```
A ab = new B();
System.out.println(ab.b);
```

This will print `16`.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the class member variable `b` in the current class `B` above. B has access to all of it member bariables no matter how they are declared.

Because `A.b` is protected but available to the calling class, you can access this by upcasting:

```
System.out.println(((A)b).b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `main()` is a member of the `B` class, it can access `private` members.